# google maps api marker with label

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: uav.Position,
            icon: mapStyles.uavSymbolBlack,
            labelContent: uav.Callsign + 
              '<div style="text-align: center;"><b>Alt: </b>' + uav.Alt + 
              '<br/><b>Bat: </b>' + 
              uav.Battery + '</div>',
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(95, 20),
            labelClass: "labels",
            labelStyle: { opacity: 0.75 },
            zIndex: 999999,})
```

This marker in my JavaScript file, but java console keep giving me an error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: MarkerWithLabel is not defined
```

I thought MarkerWithLabel is the built-in of the google maps api. But it doens't work.

Answer (score 4):

MarkerWithLabel is not part of the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), it is in a third party library [MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/).

**New location (GitHub):** https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerwithlabel

One indication is that if it was part of the API it would be google.maps.MarkerWithLabel.

(see the GitHub page for examples and documentation)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6d4vpcas/)

code snippet:

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        // icon: mapStyles.uavSymbolBlack,
        labelContent: "uav.Callsign" + '<div style="text-align: center;"><b>Alt: </b>' + "uav.Alt" + '<br/><b>Bat: </b>' + "uav.Battery" + '</div>',
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(95, 20),
        labelClass: "labels",
        labelStyle: {
            opacity: 0.75
        },
        zIndex: 999999,
        map: map
    })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
.labels {
    background-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerwithlabel/dist/index.min.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```