# "Uncaught TypeError: this.setValues is not a function" using Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

Trying to modify an example and use markerLabel class instead of google.maps.marker. 
Searched for a resolution here but couldn't find anything.

The `markerwithlabel` is declared as `var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({`

I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.setValues is not a function
```

Please check the codepen bellow.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LgOzRO

I tried to include only the code related to this issue and the minimal code required to reproduce this.

```
 var map;
var locations = [];

function initialiseMap() {
  $.getJSON("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1fBLlw8xlO_yhL8rYfFlQnzvKR-swEtE7NRX41ysARCk/values/Sheet1!A2:Q?key=AIzaSyD112yF6ORTtrx1-ugfhJLcx1VHDOla1Vs", function(data) {
        // data.values contains the array of rows from the spreadsheet. Each row is also an array of cell values.
        // Modify the code below to suit the structure of your spreadsheet.
        $(data.values).each(function() {
            var location = {};
                location.title = this[2];
                location.latitude = parseFloat(this[15]);
                location.longitude = parseFloat(this[16]);

                locations.push(location);
        });

      // Center on (0, 0). Map center and zoom will reconfigure later (fitbounds method)
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0)
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
      setLocations(map, locations);
  });
}


function setLocations(map, locations) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  // Create nice, customised pop-up boxes, to appear when the marker is clicked on
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Content String"
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var new_marker = createMarker(map, locations[i], infowindow);
    bounds.extend(new_marker.position);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function createMarker(map, location, infowindow) {

  // Modify the code below to suit the structure of your spreadsheet (stored in variable 'location')
  var position = {
    lat: parseFloat(location.latitude),
    lng: parseFloat(location.longitude)
  };
  var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: position,
    map: map,
    title: location.title,
     labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
        labelInBackground: false,
        icon: pinSymbol('red')
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

  });
  return marker;
}

function pinSymbol(color) {
    return {
        path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
        fillColor: color,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeWeight: 2,
        scale: 2
    };
}
```

Comment: How are you including the `MarkerWithLabel` third party library?

Comment: @geocodezip in the html portion of the codepen <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google maps api marker with label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687094/google-maps-api-marker-with-label)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're having a sequencing issue on the HTML side. When loading Javascript with a `<script>` tag, you should use `async` *or* `defer`, not both. In this case, the Google API should be loaded *after* the page's Javascript such that the callback, `initialiseMap`, is defined in time, so it should have the `defer` attribute. However, the Google API needs to be loaded *before* the V3 `MarkerWithLabel` is loaded, so the V3 script also needs the `defer` attribute *and* needs to go after the Google API script.

So your HTML should be

```
<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD112yF6ORTtrx1-ugfhJLcx1VHDOla1Vs&callback=initialiseMap"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
```

Comment: jsfiddle and codepen have an option for the javascript portion to load after the html so I don't think that's the issue? I tried using "defer" and the issue persists, any other ideas?

Comment: Try again then.

Comment: @Victor-------- make sure you remove the `async` attribute from the Google script, it will cause the Google script to load whenever the request to get it completes instead of deferring.

Comment: wow, ok. Javascript definitely makes me feel like an idiot. Better error descriptions would be nice. Thank you