# How to use <br /> in google map label's text:

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How can I use `br` in google map label's text. I tried to use like below. But not worked out. Any specific way to use this? ??

```js
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: this.map,
    icon: 'img/background.png',
    label: {
        text: "name: " + String(account.name) + "\ncity :" + String(account.city),
        color: "#fff",
    },
    position: {
        lat: parseFloat(account.lat),
        lng: parseFloat(account.lng)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\n`, like this

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: myLatLng,
   map: map,
   title: 'Hello\nWorld!'
});
```

You can read more about Google Maps Markers here 
[Simple Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)

Comment: it's not working.. I am not sure if I use it right or not, you can check the editted code in the question...

Comment: Sorry I thought you ment the title. Check out this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687094/google-maps-api-marker-with-label